# How to make %{HTTP_HOST} always return non-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this redirect code and I want it to always return %{HTTP_HOST} as non-www no matter what sub-domain was used.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mywebsite.com/%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]
```

So, www.website2.com , website2.com , anything.website2.com will always be redirected to `http://www.mywebsite.com/website2.com`

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Google, and click the first link.
http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/

Then you can just change the RewriteCond to match anything, rather than specifically not-www

Comment: If it was a simple case of redirecting www to non-www I would have done it without posting a question .. believe me. But unfortunately, as you may notice from my code this redirect will be not be used for one domain only but it will used to redirect hundred of domains (more like wildcard redirect) to one dynamic url on my main website so I don't have enough knowledge/experience to adopt the code to do that. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: @Dido Apologies for the abrupt reply. The link I copied will redirect any host which doesn't begin with www, so if you go to puppies.example.com it will not begin with www and thus be redirected, as with kittens.example.com or my-made-up-sub-domain.example.com - hope this makes it clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
# we are now working on HTTP_REFERER,
# change to appropriate variable according to your needs
#   check if we got at least 2 dots in the URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.([^\.]+)\.([A-Z]{2,3})$ [NC]
#   if the condition was met, redirect using only last 2 parts of URL
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.com/%1.%2 [R,L]
```

Let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have your Rewrite rule like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:[^.]+\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```